# eGPUs to enable utilization of (even) more monitors with MacBook Pro?

Tags: display, gpu, high-sierra

I know this is not the primary use case for using external GPUs, but I drank the [Space to Think](https://doi.org/10.1145/1753326.1753336) kool-aid in a serious way. Can anyone **find a source or share personal experience** that confirms that I could potentially use e.g. 2 additional (to the spec below) 4K or 5K monitors with a new MBP (so e.g. 4 5K monitors: 2 powered by internal MacBook Pro GPU and 2 powered by an external GPU)?

[According to Apple](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/), the new MacBook Pro (MacBookPro14,3 A1707, sans eGPU),

> **Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:**
>
> Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
>
> Up to four displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple hasn't made any comments about this yet. I think no one will be able to answer your question at this time.